# In my fetched json data, how can I seperate out the balance?

Tags: json, python-3.6, cryptocurrency

So, I have been testing block.io api, and so far I have this:

```
knee = block_io.get_address_balance(labels='shibe1')
s1 = json.dumps(knee)
d2 = json.loads(s1)
print (d2)
```

It returns me with this batch of text:

```
{'status': 'success', 'data': {'network': 'DOGE', 'available_balance': '0.0', 'pending_received_balance': '0.0', 'balances': [{'user_id': 1, 'label': 'shibe1', 'address': 'A9Bda9UMBcb1183PtsBxnbj5QgP6jwkCFG', 'available_balance': '0.00000000', 'pending_received_balance': '0.00000000'}]}}
```

How would I get it so that I could grab only the available_balance part of it, and print it out instead of all of the json data?

EDIT: Please help! Cant find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try using some regex.

```
import re
data="{'status': 'success', 'data': {'network': 'DOGE', 'available_balance': '0.129', 
'pending_received_balance': '0.0', 'balances': [{'user_id': 1, 'label': 'shibe1', 
'address': 'A9Bda9UMBcb1183PtsBxnbj5QgP6jwkCFG', 'available_balance': '0.00000000', 
'pending_received_balance': '0.00000000'}]}}"
pattern = re.compile("(?<=available_balance': ').*?(?=')")
matches = pattern.finditer(data)

for match in matches:
    print(match.group())
```

Breakdown : 

`import re` imports the regex library built into python

`data="{'status': 'success', 'data': {'network': 'DOGE', 'available_balance': '0.129', 
    'pending_received_balance': '0.0', 'balances': [{'user_id': 1, 'label': 'shibe1', 
    'address': 'A9Bda9UMBcb1183PtsBxnbj5QgP6jwkCFG', 'available_balance': '0.00000000', 
    'pending_received_balance': '0.00000000'}]}}"` is a string containing the data to match. You can replace this with the json data.

`pattern = re.compile("(?<=available_balance': ').*?(?=')")` compiles the regex for finding the data for available balance.

**Regex breakdown**

- `(?<=` is a lookbehind, which means it will check if the value is actually `available_balance`.
- `.*` matches everything inside a defined constraint.
- `(?=` is a lookahead, which means it will match everything before the close parenthesis, and everything after the lookbehind.

  `pattern.finditer(data)` matches the regex against `data`

`for match in matches:
    print(match.group())` prints the matches from the regex.

If you compile this code, you will get the following results : 

`0.129
0.00000000`


If you want the code under your variables, here you go :

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("(?<=available_balance': ').*?(?=')")
matches = pattern.finditer(d2)

for match in matches:
    print(match.group())
```